# Can the Box File Picker display thumbnails, or must use API?

Tags: box-api, box

I have a requirement to present files from Cloud storage (Box).  The [File Picker](https://box-content.readme.io/docs/the-box-file-picker) looks great and easy.  However I also have a requirement to display thumbnails.  I don't see this available in the File Picker.  Would that force me into writing a custom File Picker utilizing the API?

Answer (score 0):

The Box File Picker appears to simply be a thin javascript wrapper around a PHP app hosted by Box. I think you're going to have to write your own.